# could this hibernate exception be caused by database connection pooling?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, session

I've just entered the SIT phase with a Spring Boot app server deployed on Tomcat 7 using MySQL in AWS

Tomcat7 is running on a Ubuntu EC2 instance with MySQL on the standard DB server

Initially id set up my database connection in my hibernate.cfg.xml file

however i was getting problems with stale connections

the pattern was always the same after server startup

1) for around 24hours no issues
2) 24 - 48 hours - DB connections would start failing, first at a rate of about 1 in ten then to about 2 in 3 after 48 hours

lots of reading around suggested that

a) I should really configure my datasources via JNDI
b) I should not use auto connect in the DB URL as thats been deprecated
c) using the testOnBorrow property should ensure my application server doesn't attempt to use a connection that will fail

So I went ahead and set that up

heres how i configured by JDNI in my server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/FootyPicksData"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="[my db user]"
              password="[my DB passoword]"
              url="jdbc:mysql://[my DB url]
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              maxActive="15"
              maxIdle="3"
              maxWait="5000"
              removeAbandoned="false"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="20"
              logAbandoned="true"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="3600000"
              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
              numTestsPerEvictionRun="10"
              testWhileIdle="true"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              testOnReturn="false"
              />
```

So i set this up and off i went

after about 24 hours same problems appeared

well , i thought this hasn't worked lets check the logs

Now I'm getting a different error , but in exactly the same ratios (10% ish after 24 hours , 70% ish after 48 hours

```
ERROR] 2017-08-13 08:21:23.872 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/v1/leagues/user] due to exception [Transaction not successfully sta$
org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at com.footy.picks.deviceregistration.DeviceRegistrationServiceImpl.getDeviceRegistrationById(DeviceRegistrationServiceImpl.java:46) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.footy.picks.controller.FootyPicksControllerV1.getLeagues(FootyPicksControllerV1.java:847) ~[classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE$
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEA$
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.ja$
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624) ~[servlet-api-3.0.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731) ~[servlet-api-3.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:244) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at com.footy.picks.logging.AnotherLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AnotherLoggingFilter.java:53) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]

 at org.springframework.web.filter.AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractRequestLoggingFilter.java:244) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at com.footy.picks.logging.AnotherLoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(AnotherLoggingFilter.java:53) ~[classes/:?]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:61) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:92) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:221) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436) [tomcat-catalina-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote-7.0.68.jar:7.0.68]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

Well off I google again and lots of the answers suggest this is a fundamental issue with how i'm managing my DB sessions via Hibernate

at this point its worth adding that when setting up Hibernate there was 2 main design patterns, one in which you explicitly open and close connections yourself, another where you begin and commit transactions, you grab a session using getSession(), which as far as I can understand will attempt to grab an existing session , if none exists open one

so for example heres a snippet of how all of my data layer services work

```
public boolean saveOrUpdateLeagueMember(LeagueMember leagueMember) {




        Session session = HibernateUtility.getSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        try {



            session.saveOrUpdate(leagueMember);

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println(e);

            logger.error(e);

            session.getTransaction().commit();

            return false;
        }


    }
```

then some Spring magic somewhere will close the session

What is going on? is the issue in the application code or in the pooling set up ?

if its the code why its fine for 24 hours then slowly starts to fail?

Is there just something fundamentally wrong with how I've set this up?

That feels most likely as this is pretty standard stuff I'm trying to do here...

Comment: Why do you have transaction commit on getDeviceRegistrationById ? why it is @transactional ? Show us this method and getLeagues from Controller. Do you have autocommit or  SessionInViewFilter  or transaction on request?

Comment: Why are you handling transactions manually? Especially in such a simple case.

Comment: Why are you committing transaction in the catch block? It should do rollback.

Comment: Rafal G - because this is the example I followed from a tutorial - whats the other option let Spring do it for me ? Is that as simple as using the @transactional annotation ?

Comment: John Tribe I'll add this when I'm back - not sure I get your questions about auto commit - I'm not using @transactional